# Why does `min()` call a key function when there is only one item in the Iterable?

Tags: python, sorting

It seems that the Python builtin function `min()` calls
a specified key function even if there is only one item left:

```python
foo = ['2']
def key_func(value):
    print("Key function called")
    return int(value)
print(min(foo, key=key_func))
```

gives:

```
Key function called
2
```

The same observation holds for `max()` and `sorted()` as well.

Why is there no shortcut for `len(iterable) == 1`?
Imagine the case when `key_func` does an expensive calculation that
is of no use then.

I read the Python documentation but found no explanation for this behaviour, yet I assume there must be one, because the Python Core Developer Team is known to be extremely rigorous when defining and justifying the behaviour of the language and the standard library.

Comment: @Elerium115 How is it a good question? `min` does what it says, exactly as documented. End of story. Why something *does't* do something it didn't say it would do is usually a pointless question. Because it doesn't. That's why.

Comment: @deceze It would also prevent [Sort by price and remove prices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75414359/3080723), although some would argue that would be a good thing :-p

Comment: @deceze "Because it doesn't" is not a good answer. Others have provided good comments and answers for the question. But it's perfectly normal to wonder why wouldn't `min` do lazy evaluation for only one element and not call `key_func`, similar to what happens with logical operators. OP has provided a specific, answerable and reproducible question. Looks good to me, or at least not as bad as to deserve downvotes.

Comment: @Elerium115 One can come up with any number of reasons why it _mightn't_. But whether that is the _real_ reason it _doesn't_ we'll hardly know. Unless there's some public discussion around this to be dug up, which provides actual historical reasons. But the only real fact is that it simply doesn't. Period. Maybe because there are good reasons why it shouldn't, or because simply nobody thought to implement it that way.

Comment: @deceze Nevertheless, "Why isn't this simple optimisation used?" is a good question, with a possible answer "Because it's not so simple and everything is a compromise", and although we can't necessarily say why one compromise was chosen instead of another, it's possible to explain why the optimisation is not as absolutely-always-good as it seems, and what other compromises are possible.

Comment: @Stef I wonder whether there is or should be a canonical Q&A for that. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75354384/why-is-b-pop0-over-200-times-slower-than-del-b0-for-bytearray#comment132970736_75354915) comes to mind for me, where I also mention a few general reasons. (And ha, not even I thought of my old sort-by-pop question here :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the fact that the length of the iterable may not be known in advance. I completely missed that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to choose one and cannot have both:

- Guarantee that `key` is always called exactly once per item, in the original order of the items in the iterable;
- Avoid calling `key` on the item of an iterable that contains exactly one item.

It is not obvious at all that one of these two conventions is better than the other, and a programmer who calls `min` or `sorted` and cares about the second convention can add a provision in their own code to that effect, and not call `sorted` at all when the iterable has only one item.

Note that not all iterables are sequences like `list` and `tuple`; some iterables do not support `len`, so the only way to check whether they have one item or more than one item before calling `key` would be to get the first item, try getting the second item, and only if `StopIteration` wasn't raised when trying to get the second item, then call `key` on the first item.

> Imagine the case when key_func does an expensive calculation that is of no use then.

This is possible, but probably not the vast majority of use-cases of key functions; in many cases the key is just `operator.itemgetter(...)` or `lambda x: x[1].upper()` or something similar. If key_func does an expensive calculation, you probably don't want to use `key=key_func`, which throws away the result immediately after the job is done; you probably want to keep the result of the calculation to avoid recalculating them next time they'll be needed.

When key_func does an expensive calculation, your proposed optimisation is good, but can be done explicitly by the user by checking the number of items before calling `sorted` or `min`; and when key_func does not do an expensive calculation, which is probably the majority of cases, your proposed optimisation would be more expensive than just calling the key function unconditionally.

Comment: Worth mentioning explicitly that the proposed optimization would be more expensive than just calling the key function unconditionally for the vast majority of key functions.

Comment: @chepner Like this?

Comment: @chepner I agree that it would be expensive for Iterables that do not support `len()`, but would you also call it expensive for sequences where `len()`is O(1)?

Comment: The length doesn't matter. You can either just call `key` on what turns out to be the only element in the iterable, or you can waste time trying to figure out if you are avoiding a single call to `key`.

Comment: If the key function is that expensive, the caller can put some effort into determine if the call to `min` is necessary in the first place (which it isn't for single-item iterables, since the minimum value is, by definition, the only value.